# Migrating from Flow to Typescript: $Keys equivalent in TS?

Tags: typescript, flowtype

Flow has the handy `$Keys` utility function that can extract the keys from an object and create a union of string literals. So you can do:

```
const foo = {
   input: Input,
   button: Button,
   select: Select
}

type FormType = $Keys<typeof foo>      // FormType now is: 'input' | 'button' | 'select'
```

Does Typescript have an equivalent function? I know of [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html) but that only gets the keys of an `interface`, when Flow can get the keys of an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent is the `keyof` type operator:

```
type FormType = keyof typeof foo
```